# Get date range after date selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a database table (customer) with 4 columns

```
Name
Lastname
StartDate
StopDate
```

The start and stop dates can run over several days, i.e.

```
StartDate          StopDate

01.01.2015 00:00 - 01.01.2015 01:00 - Period is 1 hour
01.01.2015 00:00 - 01.05.2015 01:00 - Period is 4 days
01.01.2015 00:00 - 01.10.2015 01:00 - Period is 9 days
```

I have an ASP .Net calendar control. When a user clicks a date on this calendar i would like to return the dates in the following manner

If `01.01.2015` is selected the ALL 3 records above would be returned
If `02.01.2015` is selected only the last 2 records would be returned (as the 1st record has now expired)
If `03.01.2015` is selected only the last 2 records would be returned (as the 1st record has now expired)
If `06.01.2015` is selected only the last record would be returned (as the top 2 have now expired)

Hope this makes sense?

So my attempt to carry this out has led some confusion using Linq to SQL

```
Private IQueryable<Insurer> GetInsurers(DateTime UserSelectedDate)
{
    return db.Insurers(dt=> dt.StartDate >= UserSelectedDate && dt.StopDate <= UserSelectedDate)
}
```

I've tried other variations including some on the internet but not getting the results im after which usually means im missing something critical here (or ive exhausted myself).... Any idea?

Comment: No - if there's a startdate on 20.01.2015 and the user selects 01.01.2015 then it would show 20.1.2015 - but it shouldnt - think of it like a calendar in Outlook with a meeting lasting couple of days. You would only see the meeting over the days you have entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just swap the position of your variable in query.

```
private IQueryable<Insurer> GetInsurers(DateTime UserSelectedDate)
{
    return db.Insurers(dt=> UserSelectedDate >= dt.StartDate && UserSelectedDate <= dt.StopDate)
}
```

Which means UserSelectedDate should be after or same as start date and should end before or at end date.